# netusergetinfo return 2221

Tags: windows

netusergetinfo is returning 2221 error code for valid user . What is the reason? It is because of some security setting on active directory but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: hmm... we need a lot more information.

Comment: I have to validate the existence of a active directory user. For looking up user I use this function, netusergetinfo .

This function works on my local setup but is giving error 2221 on a production active directory. I suspect this due to some settings of active directory, but I can't figure that out

Comment: errorcode 2221 means "NERR_UserNotFound".

Comment: errorcode 2221 means "NERR_UserNotFound".

I know that, but it is giving it for a user which exists.

Comment: my process which call netusergetinfo runs under the SYSTEM account

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have the same problem as described here [Get current user's last logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371807/get-current-users-last-logon/).

One possible reason is that you don't use UNICODE format for the user name.

Another problem is if you try to ask the name of **domain user**. In this case you should use not a form

```
nStatus = NetUserGetInfo (NULL, L"Domain\\TestUser", dwLevel, (LPBYTE *) & pBuf);
```

but use as the first parameter the name of a domain controller from a domain which has trust to domain "Domain". You can use [DsGetDcName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675983.aspx) or [NetGetAnyDCName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370419.aspx) or [NetGetDCName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370420.aspx) to get this name.

To answer on your question exactly you should post the corresponding source code and describe shortly your domain environment and the role of the computer and the current user under which current process are running.

Answer (score 0):

API: NetUserSetInfo / netusergetinfo
Error Code: 2221 
Reason: The Username you are trying to update is not present in the system.

for reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/netmgmt/network-management-error-codes