# How to get logonserver name in AD domain programatically

Tags: windows, active-directory

A host which part of Active directory domain does authentication from the logon server (domain controller).

LOGONSERVER env var has its value.

C:>echo %LOGONSERVER% \PUN5OPSDIRPIN01

Is there any API using which I can retrieve this value?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the information is [LsaGetLogonSessionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378290.aspx) API which allocate and return back [SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380128.aspx) structure contains `LogonServer` field. The input parameter `LUID LogonId` you can get from [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671.aspx) which you should call with the `TokenInformationClass` parameter set to `TokenStatistics`. The field `AuthenticationId` the [TOKEN_STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379632.aspx) struct is the LUID which one need to use.

In the answer [Get current user's last logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371807/get-current-users-last-logon) I posted an code example which shows how to get this and some other information about the current login session.